# Node.js работает только один воркер

Tags: node.js, express, cluster

Вот входная точка моего сервера:

```
const numCPUs: number = require('os').cpus().length;
const PORT = process.env.PORT;

import server from './app';
import logger from './logger';

import Domain = require('domain');
import cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    logger.info(`Master ${process.pid} is running`);

    for (let i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        logger.info(`Worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
        cluster.fork();
    });

  } else {
    const domain = Domain.create();
    domain.on('error', (error) => {
        logger.error(`Domain error in precess id:${ process.pid }`, error);
        ...
    });

    domain.run(() => {
        server.listen(PORT, () => {
            logger.info(`Express server id:${ process.pid } listening on port ${ PORT }`);
        });
    });
}
```

Создал тестовую страничку, в которой при нажатии на кнопочку отправляется 20 (варьируется) запросов на определенный хэндрел. Вот его код:

```
app.route('/api/admin/getProjectFilters')
    .get( async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
        try {
            const filters: projectFiltersType = {...};
            // some actions

            logger.info(`project filters were sent to admin in precess id:${ process.pid }`);
            res.status(200).send(filters);

        } catch (error) {
            logger.error(`project filters sending to admin failed in precess id:${ process.pid }`, error);
            res.status(500).send(error);
        }
    }
);
```

Запускаю сервер, жмакаю по тестовой кнопочке, и вижу в консоли:

```
2018-10-10T08:04:50.754Z [info]: Master 9584 is running

2018-10-10T08:04:52.273Z [info]: Express server id:11592 listening on port 2222

2018-10-10T08:04:52.334Z [info]: Express server id:2828 listening on port 2222

2018-10-10T08:04:52.352Z [info]: Express server id:2580 listening on port 2222

2018-10-10T08:04:52.383Z [info]: Express server id:4540 listening on port 2222

2018-10-10T08:04:58.330Z [info]: project filters were sent to admin in precess id:4540

2018-10-10T08:04:58.377Z [info]: project filters were sent to admin in precess id:4540

2018-10-10T08:04:58.447Z [info]: project filters were sent to admin in precess id:4540

2018-10-10T08:04:58.491Z [info]: project filters were sent to admin in precess id:4540

2018-10-10T08:04:58.538Z [info]: project filters were sent to admin in precess id:4540
```

Как видно, запускается несколько воркеров, но на запросы всегда отвечает один и тот же.

Как мне заставить воркеров работать поочередно?

Comment: на первый взгляд у тебя всё нормально, просто запросы подхватывает один и тот же worker. проверь эту поделку большим количеством запросов: `ab -c 20 -n 100 http://localhost:2222/tra-ta-ta`

Comment: А зачем им работать поочередно, если один воркер успевает отвечать на все запросы?

Comment: Кстати, кластер - это все процессы вместе. Отдельные процессы называются воркерами, а не кластерами.

Comment: @norbornen ну 20 это для примера. максимально я тестировал с 100 запросами. в принципе и с 20 видна проблема (см. след. комментарий)

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov если бы успевал. процесс дорогой - сначала идет выборка из бд а потом результат обрабатывается через цикл в цикле. Видно как в консоль логи падают "урывками". По поводу терминологии - Ваша правда, спасибо, поправлю.

Comment: Скорее всего это keep-alive. Проверяйте curl-ом или другими приложениями которые открывают новое соединение на каждый запрос.

Comment: @Alexey Ten попробовал запустить одновременно в двух браузерах. Жаработало! Спасибо огромное я теперь знаю, что все работает как надо))